# ssl deployment to ec2 single instance of IIS7 Windows 2008

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, amazon-web-services

As the title says i'd like to deploy from VS2010 AWS toolkit or Jenkins (preferably) an ssl cert to the website running on AWS Win2008/IIS7. Either as a redeployment or new deployment.

I've looked around and there's nothing on this, why? Appears to be possible with ElasticBeanstalk but that's not what i'm running at this stage.

Is it impossible and i'm silly for not knowing that?

If so what options do i have? I'm new to AWS so open to all suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to deploy a cert to an EC2 instance from VS2010.  I don't believe IIS provides a command line utility to import a certificate, so it would be tough for the AWS toolkit to bootstrap that for you.  If you ever get into Cloud Formation, you may find a way to do it with cfn-init and PowerShell.  Importing a cert to a Windows instace on bootup and creating an https binding that uses that cert is not something that's going to be quick to set up.

With Elastic Beanstalk, you don't have to deploy your certificate to your instances, you just have to import it to IAM, and then specify the imported certificate when you start beanstalk.  Your instance can communicate with Beanstalk's load balancer via http port 80, or you can use a self signed cert on your instance to secure communication between the instances and the load balancer.

Comment: ok thanks  - i have a meeting with an AWS solution architect next week so i'll pose the same question and see what he says - i'll post his answer